# Keyboard shortcut for "open a terminal here"

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

How can I create a keyboard shortcut so that when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> in nautilus (or desktop), I get a terminal in the current directory?

Comment: An added tip, don't use `sudo` on `dconf-editor`, run it without. Found that out the hard way, spent a few minutes rebooting and restarting before I figured it out.

Comment: Imo, this is the best answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/a/696901/499347 (short, understandable and it just works)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut for open terminal Nautilus >= 3.16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680016/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-terminal-nautilus-3-16)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Edit: not anymore applicable for Ubuntu 16.10 and newer**

Finally figured it out.. first `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools nautilus-open-terminal`, then run `dconf-editor` and set the `org/gnome/desktop/interface/can-change-accels` boolean on.  Then open nautilus using this command (to disable Unity global menu Temporarily):

```
nautilus -q
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 nautilus
```

Now you can mouseover the action in the file menu, and change the accel by typing your key while the action is highlighted, finally restart your nautilus.  If you don't see Open in terminal in the File menu and you've just installed `nautilus-open-terminal`, you might need to first run `nautilus -q`.

[image]

[image]

**Ubuntu 14.04 and up**

If you can't find the `can-change-accels` key in your dconf configuration you can try the following solution:

1. Stop nautilus by executing `nautilus -q`
2. Open `~/.config/nautilus/accels` in a text editor of your choice, e.g. gedit:

   ```
    gedit ~/.config/nautilus/accels
   ```
3. Try to see if you can find the following line:

   ```
    ;(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "")
   ```
4. If the line exists, add your keyboard shortcut in the second double-quoted segment and uncomment the line by removing `;`:

   ```
    (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "F12")
   ```

   This would set the shortcut to <kbd>F12</kbd>. For a list of all possible key codes please consult  [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/511030/81372).

   If the line doesn't exist just copy and paste the one found in this answer at the end of the file.
5. Save the file and restart Nautilus by clicking on the Nautilus icon in your launcher/dash.

### Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04

Here, the relevant command in `~/.config/nautilus/accels` is `TerminalNautilus:OpenFolderLocal`. (`NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal` is still present in the file, but doesn't seem to have any effect.) So follow the instructions above, except change the line

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ExtensionsMenuGroup/TerminalNautilus:OpenFolderLocal" "")
```

to

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ExtensionsMenuGroup/TerminalNautilus:OpenFolderLocal" "F12")
```

to make F12 your keyboard shortcut. Notice that `;` is again removed.

Finally, **log out** for changes to take effect.

Comment: The trick with F12 key doesn't work for me :(

Comment: As indicated in the answer, use `dconf-editor`. Using `gconf-editor` may not help.

Comment: Not working for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @DpN  For 14.04 try editing in the file `~/.config/nautilus/accels` and adding a line like `(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "F12")`, then restart nautilus.

Comment: Not working,I inserted after 'Connect to server' line in that accels file starting with ;

Comment: They `; ` is a comment, you have to remove that

Comment: Just adding that same works in Nemo, but the file to be edited is `~/.gnome2/accels/nemo`.

Comment: I have a 14.04 and the approach for it didn't work; however, I used that for 15.04 and above and it works like a charm.

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 16.04 but seems not working for 16.10.

Comment: not working in 17.10..

Comment: According to the other answer this answer has not been functioning for quite a few versions of Ubuntu now. This should be edited into the answer more clearly! Could someone do this. Alternatively please upvote comments that indicate that this no longer works for 16.10 and newer.

Comment: Cannot test this, but maybe `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface can-change-accels true` should be done for this to work?

Answer (score 40):

Since version 3.15.4 Nautilus doesn't load the accel file anymore [(Source)](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/blob/master/NEWS#L986).

Fortunately, there's a better approach in order to get what you want. Long explanation/useful resources can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) and also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680016/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-terminal-nautilus-3-16/696901#696901). In short:

1. Create a script called `Terminal` (yes, without an extension) inside the folder `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   gnome-terminal
   ```
2. Make it executable, then close any Nautilus instance:

   ```
   $ chmod +x Terminal
   $ nautilus -q
   ```
3. Create (or edit) the `~/.config/nautilus/scripts-accels` file adding these lines:

   ```
   F12 Terminal
   ; Commented lines must have a space after the semicolon
   ; Examples of other key combinations:
   ; <Control>F12 Terminal
   ; <Alt>F12 Terminal
   ; <Shift>F12 Terminal
   ```
4. Test it! Open Nautilus, right click, and choose Scripts > Terminal. Or, use the keyboard shortcut that you've just configured :)

**Note**: Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

**Update Ubuntu 20.10**: Unfortunately, this does not anymore work in Nautilus 3.38 (Ubuntu 20.10).

**Update Ubuntu 21.10**: Fortunately, the `scripts-accels` file works again in Files 40 (Ubuntu 21.10)

Comment: If you reopen nautilus before editing `scripts-accels`, you'll have to run `nautilus -q` again. Should probably move that instruction down?

Comment: This is the best and most recent answer, a pity that it's this low.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS! 

Comment: Tried on mine and wasn't working, but quickly figured out it's because I had removed gnome-terminal and replaced it with terminator - Works once I updated the script

Comment: The update message that states this has stopped working with Ubuntu 20.10 is probably incorrect, I had no issues using this with 20.10, and just successfully set it for 21.04.

Comment: Nice try.  
Nevertheless it's not exactly what I'm looking for, because it works only in the open folder and not in the foder where the cursor is positioned as "Right Click + Open in Terminal" does.

Comment: works in ubutnu 23.04

Answer (score 13):

Using the dconf-editor approach doesn't seem to work in Trusty Gnome. 
But the following does:

In your home directory press Ctrl+h, open the .config folder, the nautilus folder, and the accels file;

ie, open `~/.config/nautilus/accels` and change the line:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ExtensionsMenuGroup/NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal" "")
```

to

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ExtensionsMenuGroup/NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal" "F12")
```

Note that the comment delimiter has been removed.

Save the file, log out and back in.

Comment: Yep, this is the approach I have already suggested in the comment on accepted answer.

Comment: This approach works perfectly

Comment: There is no need to log out and in again. A simple `nautilus -q` does the job.

Comment: I tested this on `3.28.1` and it didn't work. Can someone please test with the same version?

Comment: I didnt't find that line

Comment: Seems not available anymore, see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1646985) bug report.

Answer (score 12):

**Not exactly the answer for this question**

If all you want is access the terminal in the current directory, you can try:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd>
or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd>

(2020) When I wrote this was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
(2024) It seems that now is <kbd>Shift</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>: Same as right click at the current directory
<kbd>e</kbd>: Selects "Open in Terminal"

---

**It can change if your OS is in another language.**

For example, in portuguese from brasil would be:
<kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> then <kbd>t</kbd>

Just look at the underlined letter to know the key.
(2024) I had to use arrow keys to be able to see the underlined letter.

---

**If you are using notebook** you may have to use the super key too:
<kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd>

---

You mentioned opening from Desktop, the closest i could think is opening the terminal on home directory:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

Comment: Valid answer, provided you indicate this is a (quite valid) workaround rather than a possibility to add a shortcut key.

Comment: This should be community wiki, lol

Comment: I know this is an Ubuntu forum but this solution also works for me on Rocky with `shift`+`F10` (instead of `ctrl`).  This is great thanks!

Comment: @brotherJ4mes I just tested and it seems that is `shift` in ubuntu too right now

Answer (score 6):

You could also use a nautilus script instead of a dedicated extension:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
# Open terminal here
#
# Nautilus script that opens a gnome-terminal at the current location, if it's
# a valid one. This could be done in shell script, but I love Perl!.
#
# 20020930 -- Javier Donaire <jyuyu@fraguel.org>
# http://www.fraguel.org/~jyuyu/
# Licensed under the GPL v2+
#
# Modified by: Dexter Ang [thepoch@mydestiny.net]
# 2003-12-08: Modified for Gnome 2.4
#       - Added checking if executed on Desktop "x-nautilus-desktop:///"
#         so that it opens in /home/{user}/Desktop

use strict;

$_ = $ENV{'NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI'};
if ($_ and m#^file:///#) {
  s/%([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/chr(hex($1))/eg;
  s#^file://##;
  exec "gnome-terminal --working-directory='$_'";
}

# Added 2003-12-08 Dexter Ang
if ($_ == "x-nautilus-desktop:///") {
  $_ = $ENV{'HOME'};
  $_ = $_.'/Desktop';
  exec "gnome-terminal --working-directory='$_'";
}
```

[Instructions on installing the script and assigning a keyboard shortcut.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236414/how-can-i-install-a-nautilus-script)

Comment: And how exactly having a Nautilus script instead of a dedicated extension helps assigning it a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @MestreLion Thank your for your comment. This answer was merged from another Q&A (check the [edit log](http://askubuntu.com/posts/68078/revisions) for more details). That's why it didn't have a section on assigning a shortcut.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Sorry then! A bit unfortunate that such distinct (albeit related) questions were *merged*. Your answer was great for the other question, but incomplete for this one.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on `John F. Healy`'s post:

```
nautilus -q
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
sed -i 's/; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>\/ExtensionsMenuGroup\/NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal" "")/(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>\/ExtensionsMenuGroup\/NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal" "F12")/g' ~/.config/nautilus/accels
```

This should work on Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn. The last line edits the `~/.config/nautilus/accels` file. To make sure the edit was successful, try the following command:

```
grep NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal ~/.config/nautilus/accels
```

Answer (score 2):

After installing `nautilus-open-terminal`, ensure that you have killed all nautilus processes (there's always one non visible nautilus process running, so use `pgrep nautilus` to find them and use then use the `kill` command).

Then if you launch nautilus, you should see the Open in Terminal if you right-click in the list of files, like I did in the screenshot below (where I was running 14.04):

[image]

Comment: The problem is I use list view where there is no white space left if the folder contains many files. Now I use tree in list view in the display setting as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Besides configuring by hand, there is also a GUI application to manage these shortcuts: https://github.com/echo-devim/nautilusaccelsmanager (tested)

It's pretty useful since the configuration fails because of tiny stuff like capitalization. With this useful tool, just press the desired hotkeys and configuration with the right style is produced.

For a detailed insight of how it works, see https://askubuntu.com/a/696901/1147792.

Answer (score 0):

Piggy backing off of Thiago Lages de Alencar's answer...

<kbd>Right mouse</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> opens a terminal.

This works in empty space or you can right click directly on desired folder.

...When using nautilus, I've typically got left hand on keyboard and right hand on mouse, so this is really natural given my hand positions.

If you want a dedicated single key shortcut you can use `xdotool` to mimic the click and keypress like below (assign this bash script to your preferred shortcut).  I do a quick check so that I don't inadvertently run this script for other windows that aren't nautilus.

```
#!/bin/bash

# is nautilus the active window?
naut_act=$(xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | grep WM_CLASS.*nautilus)
[[ -z $naut_act ]] && exit # if not exit

sleep .2 # may need adjustment 
/usr/bin/xdotool key --clearmodifiers  shift+F10 e  # may be ctrl+F10 in other distros
```