# Keyboard shortcut (accels) forgotten after reboot?

Tags: nautilus, gnome, reboot, shortcut-keys

Following on from my question here:

[Keyboard shortcut for "open a terminal here"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here)

I have found that my accels are forgotten after a reboot and have to be assigned again.  Why is this, and how can I make them 'stick' permanently?

Comment: Well it's not abandoned, just unanswered!  I'm watching it..

Comment: removed flag for closure

Comment: Have you tried Nautilus scripts? You can have "Open terminal hare" in your right click menu with [Nautilus scripts](http://askubuntu.com/q/138052/37006).

Comment: yes, i use nautilus scripts already for some other jobs .. but right click menu is not keyboard shortcut

Comment: ps: i can set keyboard shortcuts for nautilus scripts using gconf-editor, but it also seems they are forgotten after reboot

Comment: Have You tried Krusader by the way? It's a twin panel file manager by KDE guys - it has 'open terminal here'. And You can write so called UserActions - and have almost what ever You want. I've written a UserAction - to open new tab in a running Konsole - instead of firing up another instance.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem sometime ago... There the problem was that I had a profile started at startup, and I had to save changes to that profile - in order to make changes permanent.

Comment: How did you save changes to the profile?

Comment: Well - I've just made another profile with a current settings (actually I've overwritten existing one).

Comment: This is not to say - that I had the same problem as You are facing. You talk about accels - I've no idea who are they. I had a problem with another application - and there I finally found that the problem was with a profile.

Answer (score -3):

The root cause of your issues is that Gnome in general and Nautilus in particular are not designed to be easily configurable.

I'd recommend to try using a more fully featured file browser and DE.