# Custom directories in Nautilus' Copy to and Move to menus

Tags: nautilus

Nautilus has a very handy *Copy to* and *Move to* menus.

How can I add my own directories to those menus?

Comment: very similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/674/add-options-to-move-to-when-you-right-click-on-a-file

Comment: Uff, there is no way to customize this ???

Answer (score 2):

You can use Nautilus Scripts to have "Copy To" and "Move To" in right click menu. This is not exactly what you want, But a workaround.

**What are Natilus Scripts?**

Scripts are typically simpler in operation than full Nautilus extensions and can be written in any scripted language capable of being executed on your computer.

**How to use?**

Using Nautilus Scripts is very easy, You don't have to install any extra package. Just download the scripts and place them inside Nautilus Scripts folder that's it.

Follow these steps to setup "Copy To" and "Move To" in Nautilus right click menu.

- Open Nautilus and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files & folders. Navigate to ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts
- Create two new empty documents with the name "Move To" and "Copy To".
- Copy the source of "[Move To](http://gnome-look.org/CONTENT/content-files/99485-move-to)" and "[Copy To](http://gnome-look.org/CONTENT/content-files/99484-copy-to)" scripts and paste inside respective files that you've just created. Save both files.
- To make both files executable right click on each one and select properties, Under "Permissions" tab enable "Allow executing file as program". That's it!

  [image]

  [image]

**More Nautilus Scripts:**

You can download many useful Nautilus scripts from hare.

[Gnome-Look](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=188)

Comment: Looks like a good workaround. But instead of choosing the file, I want to copy the files to Samba destination: `smb://dir/name/`. How to modify this script to copy the selection and get tray notification when copied?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no official way do it now.

It only exists as an idea:

http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/24730/