# How do you add "open in terminal" to the right-click mouse menu for folders/directories?

Tags: 10.04, nautilus, mouse, menu

I would like to add it to the default menu (mouse right-click)

Like I want to right click on a folder and open it in the terminal. 
I don't want to have to find the directory in the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please define your question. For more details on best practices consider reading the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask) on asking questions.Regards

Comment: what do i need to add?

Comment: Wow, this really worked on my Ubuntu Srever 14.04

Comment: Thanks for the answer Manish Sinha, but I am not able to follow the steps. Kindly help me at the following stage so that I can proceed. I am not getting `interface` under `gnome`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You first need to install the package `nautilus-open-terminal` from Software Center or `Synaptic Package Manager`

[image: Installing Nautilus Open Terminal package]

Then goto command line and type

```
nautilus -q
```

Then open nautilus and you can find "Open in Terminal"

[image: Terminal Open from Nautilus]

If you want to assign a keyboard shortcut to this action, please consult the following Q&A:

[Keyboard shortcut for "open a terminal here"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here/445951#445951)

Comment: what about in ubuntu 10.04, there is no Unity

Comment: @Alex Press Alt+F2 and type `gconf-editor`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Good answer. Consider using a [browser script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2405/insert-apt-link-making-it-easy-to-insert-an-apt-link-into-your-question-answ) to easily add those apt links.. :)

Comment: Why do we need to check the `can_change_accels` option? Would you please explain a bit more

Comment: @manuzhang I am not very sure, but it did show up. Maybe a setting

Comment: @ManishSinha What if not?

Comment: @manuzhang I got it working that way

Comment: @ManishSinha It works for me without checking that option

Comment: @manuzhang I will try it out myself.

Comment: That's a really cool feature.  Any idea how to do that in KDE? (kubuntu).  I was able to get it to work on a folder by adding konsole --workdir  %u to Open With in a folder's properties.  That didn't work on a text file.

Comment: @Joe Maybe you should ask a new question.

Comment: @manuzhang can_change_accels is described as "Whether the user can dynamically type a new accelerator when positioned over an active menuitem."  which may sound a little cryptic.. but basically means you can add stuff to the contextual menu ..

Comment: @marc-andrebenoit any references would be helpful

Comment: @manuzhang well what i quoted was actually the long description in the gconf editor... 
an accelerator is any key or key combination or a mouse click
so what this setting says is that you can for example .. right click to have a context menu doing so then positions you over an active menuitem (the contextual menu) and it enables you to then left click ( which is a new accelerator compared to the right click you just did.. ) to finish your task of opening up a new context menu element..   from what i understand.. it is what it means.. but i may be wrong.. hence me just posting in comments.. :)

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that this isn't built in...

Comment: If nautilus doesn't automatically restart, and things are hidden on your desktop, I recommend running "nohup nautilus &" to get everything back.