# Keyboard shortcut for "open a terminal here" in Nemo

Tags: command-line, nautilus, 13.04, nemo

How can I make a keyboard shortcut for "Open a terminal here" in Nemo?

I am finding the "Files" manager formerly known as nautilus that comes with Ubuntu 13.04 to be too crippled to bother using anymore, and I have switched to Nemo file manager with good results so far.  There's just one thing I'm missing, a customisable keyboard shortcut to Open in Terminal in the current location.

[The method that I use for nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/72222/21350) doesn't work any longer because I have no key for `can-change-accels` related to nemo, and neither do I see "Open in Terminal" in the File Menu drop down.  It is, however in the right click menu in Nemo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look around in the file `~/.gnome2/accels/nemo` for a line with 'OpenInTerminal'.

Steps:

1. open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type `gedit ~/.gnome2/accels/nemo`
2. Find `OpenInTerminal` and edit this line:

   ```
   ; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "")
   ```

   with shorcut (say `<Alt>t` here) and remove the semicolon `;`:

   ```
   (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/OpenInTerminal" "<Alt>t")
   ```

This will set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> as shortcut for open in terminal.