# Where to find the legitimate key-values of nautilus accelerators?

Tags: nautilus, keyboard-accelerators

I would like to play with the various properties that nautilus supports to be modified through ~/.config/nautilus/accels.

Is there a place where I can get all the supported key-value pairs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I never found any official entry for this in the GNOME documentation, but - as pointed out in [my answer on installing Nautilus scripts](https://askubuntu.com/a/236415/81372) - you can use the keycodes [reported by `xev`](https://askubuntu.com/a/466660/81372) for the most part.

The only exceptions I found were the various modifier keys:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> = `<Primary>`
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> = `<Alt>`
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> = `<Shift>`

As for the different properties/actions controllable through the `accels` file: As far as I know the only actions supported are the ones already listed in the file by default (though commented out).