# Quick way to open terminal in current folder in nautilus?

Tags: unity, nautilus, gnome-terminal

I use the nautilus-open-terminal package. Before upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04, nautilus used to have a settings button on the top right panal where you can click something like "open in terminal " to open the terminal here. After upgrading to 14.04, the settings icon is gone and I have to return to the parent folder and right click on the folder to open terminal here. (Because in **list view** the folder might have many files so that there is no white space I can right click to show the "Open in terminal" menu.)

The solution mentioned here: [Keyboard shortcut for "open a terminal here"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here) doesn' t seem to work for me.