# Launch file manager from terminal with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: command-line, nautilus, shortcut-keys

I would like to use a keyboard shortcut to launch the file manager in the working directory of the terminal (the reverse equivalent of [Keyboard shortcut for "open a terminal here"](https://askubuntu.com/q/68078/81372)).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A keyboard shortcut like this doesn't exist by default, but you can use the bash built-in `bind` to define one.

Just add the following section to your `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
# define function that opens default FM in working directory
fmhere(){
    xdg-open "$PWD"
}
# bind hotkey to it (<Alt><Shift><F>)
bind -x '"\eF":"fmhere"'
```

`\eF` is the terminal escape sequence of my keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Check out [@slm's excellent answer over at unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89624/29245) to learn how to determine the correct escape code for your keyboard shortcut of choice.

Another quick way to determine the escape code:

Open your terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Now press your favorite keyboard shortcut. The correct escape code should appear. Just make sure to replace `^[` with `\e` before adding the shortcut to your `.bashrc`, e.g. replace `^[F` with `\eF`.

---

**Sources**:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89622/29245