# Launch nautilus in location navigated to in Terminal

Tags: command-line, nautilus, filesystem

I find it rather hard to travel through my system using nautilus and much prefer using the `cd` etc commands in Terminal to get around my system, but I find that sometimes I do need to look at a list of files and folders in nautilus as `ls` just isn't doing it for me and maybe there is such a large number of files that it would be much simpler if I could just have them all listed in a GUI instead of having to get ls to redirect the output into a file that I would then have to read.

But then what I find is that I have very quickly found the location of the directory which contains the files I want, in Terminal, and then I have to go back into nautilus and slowly move to that location through the GUI, so I am wondering if there is any way in Terminal, once you have used `cd` to get to your target directory, to launch nautilus and have it auto-navigate to that location (so that it opens the directory you have used `cd` to get to in nautilus)?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu15.1
  Candidate: 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu15.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu15.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.10.1-0ubuntu15 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Related: [Launch file manager from terminal with a keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512447/launch-file-manager-from-terminal-with-a-keyboard-shortcut).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the [nemo file manager](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo): it has a terminal-and-file-manager-in-one.

[image: Steampunk customised nemo]

My nemo is customised with home-brewn steam punk icons, but you get the point... **;-)**

Commands to install:

```
sudo sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

Optional packages: (bold ones are the ones I've got installed as well)

- nemo-dbg - File manager and graphical shell for Unity (Debugging symbols)
- **nemo-data - File manager and graphical shell for Unity (data files)**
- **nemo-fileroller - File Roller integration for Nemo**
- nemo-dropbox - Dropbox integration for Nemo
- nemo-compare - Context menu comparison extension for Nemo file manager
- python-nemo - Python binding for Nemo components
- **nemo-seahorse - seahorse plugins and utilities for encryption**
- **nemo-share - Nemo extension to share folder using Samba**
- nemo-pastebin - Nemo extension to send files to a pastebin
- nemo-rabbitvcs - Nemo extension for RabbitVCS
- nemo-media-columns - Nemo Extension
- **nemo-terminal - Nemo extension to enable an embedded terminal**
- **nemo-image-converter - nemo extension to mass resize or rotate images**
- **nemo-emblems - Change a folder or file emblem**
- **nemo-filename-repairer - Nemo extension for filename encoding repair**
- nemo-folder-color - Change a folder color

Comment: Where do you find the terminal extension? github or ppa? I didn't find it in the repo.

Comment: @SylvainPineau repository added!  Thanks for the upvote and comment!

Answer (score 28):

From your terminal, just open `nautilus` as follow:

```
nautilus .
```

It will open a new instance of Nautilus in the directory where you were in your Terminal.

From the `nautilus` man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       nautilus [options] URIs...
```

Comment: *This* is the answer to the question asked.

Comment: Use `(nautilus . >/dev/null 2>&1 &)` to run independent of terminal process and suppress log appear in current shell session. Consider set it as alias such as `na`.

Answer (score 11):

As well as

```
nautilus .
```

you can also do:

```
xdg-open .
```

and it will do the same as if you double clicked a file in nautilus.  Which also means you can open a spreadsheet in LibreOffice with

```
xdg-open mysheet.ods
```

etc.  I have it aliased to `xopen` for slightly quicker typing by putting the following in my `.bashrc`

```
alias xopen=xdg-open
```

Answer (score 8):

Once inside your terminal, simply type `nautilus .` to open a new nautilus window.

There is also a file explorer for the terminal itself. Type:

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

Then when in a directory, type `mc` to open it.

Screenshot of Midnight Commander(MC) File Manager:

[image: (MC File Manager Picture)]

I use MC all the time in tty. It's mainly keyboard shortcuts and although you can click the buttons, you should learn the shortcuts. BTW, the numbers at the bottom are function keys so <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>...

Comment: Cool!  I didn't know about `mc`!  Upvoted!  ;-)

Comment: Excellent suggestion, one more vote :)

Comment: MC is short for midnight commander, by the way.

Comment: @T I know but it's just easier to type MC

Answer (score 1):

An even more general approach than those already presented - I have the following in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
open() {
  for file in "$@"
  do
    xdg-open "$file" > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
      echo "$file"": Failed to open"
    else
      echo "$file"": Opened successfully"
    fi

  done
}
```

`xdg-open` is a useful program that opens something as though you double clicked it, but it works from the terminal. The `> /dev/null 2>&1` discards the `stdout` from whatever program opens your file or directory, as this can be really annoying. With this you can open multiple directories in one line, e.g.

```
open . .. Documents
```

Will open 3 windows, the current directory, the directory above the current directory and the `Documents` folder in the current directory, all with your default file manager, be it `nautilus` or `nemo`.

Naturally, it will also open other types of files e.g. `open file.doc` will open `file.doc` in LibreOffice.