# Is there a way to change a 'searching box' to an 'executing box'?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

When you start typing in Gnome desktop environment a little search-box pop out one the bottom right of the screen ( Im guessing it's a nautilus feature). I could really use an quick execution-box which will work the same (without unnecessary opened windows). Is there way to do it ?

Comment: I would suggest that you have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/a/602877/364819

Comment: And report back whether that is / is not what you need! (Thanks @ParanoidPanda)