# How to get Nautilus to open in location navigated to in Terminal on 15.10

Tags: command-line, gnome, nautilus

What I normally do is `cd` to a location in Terminal, and then run (as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/602873/364819)):

```
nautilus .
```

If I want to open Nautilus so that it opens up on the location to which I have navigated to in Terminal, however, no matter to where I navigate in 15.10, running the command only ever opens Nautilus in the home folder. If I want it to open a specific location then I have to instead run:

```
nautilus /path/to/location/
```

So why am I not able to just run the original command to get there? This is rather inconvenient. Is this a bug? And is there any way of making it work as it did before?

---

**OS Information:**

```
 LSB Version:   core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
 Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
 Description:   Ubuntu 15.10
 Release:   15.10
 Codename:  wily
```

**Package Information:**

```
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.18.1-0ubuntu1~wily1
  Candidate: 1:3.18.1-0ubuntu1~wily1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.18.1-0ubuntu1~wily1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.14.2-0ubuntu12 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You can do this by `nautilus .` in ubuntu 15.10

Comment: This works with nautilus 1:3.14.2-0ubuntu12 in Ubuntu 15.10. I note that you are running a newer version of nautilus available from the gnome3-team which may behave differently.

Comment: I second Charles Green, `nautilus .` works perfectly using Nautilus from the default repositories, it's probably a bug in Nautilus from the GNOME repository.

Comment: `nautilus .` works here with Ubuntu 15.10 and GNOME 3.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nautilus .` works perfectly using the Nautilus version from the default repositories, so it's probably a bug in the Nautilus version from the GNOME repository.

As a workaround until the bug is fixed, you may use this command to open Nautilus in the current working directory:

```
nautilus "$PWD"
```