# Adding run as root for nautilus in unity

Tags: permissions, nautilus, root, .desktop, launcher

I am seeking for a way to make run as root option shown in "Files" context menu of Unity so, I get rid of using terminal every time I want to access nautilus as a root.

[image]

I found the original concept here, except for I didn`t find the file need to edit:
[How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root)

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @JacobVlijm it is 15.10

Comment: Ok. thanks will post an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Maythux I don't think so. The (this) question is on how to add it to the Unity Launcher as a right- click option (*shown in "Files" context menu of Unity*). Also, 15.10 uses a different ` .desktop` file in the launcher, so even if you take *the answers* as a criterion (which you shouldn't) , it would be outdated.

Comment: @Maythux again, *the question* is the criterion, not possible answer(s), *and* the answer is even outdated for 15.10.

Comment: @JacobVlijm ok its my fault.sorry

Comment: Also see [How to start Nautilus as root](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### To add the option to run as root to the nautilus (`Files`) launcher:

1. Copy the `.desktop` file, representing nautilus in the launcher, from the global directory `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`

   which is **on 14.04 and 14.10** : `nautilus.desktop`:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```

   and **on 15.04 and 15.10** : `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the file with (e.g.) `gedit`, look for the line:

   ```
   Actions=Window;
   ```

   Change it into:

   ```
   Actions=Window;Open as root;
   ```

   Add to the very end of the file:

   ```
   [Desktop Action Open as root]
   Name=Open as root
   Exec=gksu nautilus
   ```

   Save and close the file.
3. Install `gksu`, to be able to enter your password via GUI:

   [image]

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gksu
   ```
4. Finally, log out/in to make Unity "aware" of the local, edited `.desktop` file.

   [image]

That's about it.

#### Note

In some cases, you might have some doubts on what is the correct `.desktop` file to edit. This question on `nautilus` is a good example, since nautilus represents itself in a different `.desktop` file in the launcher on different Ubuntu versions, while nautilus has multiple `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications`.

To be sure to edit the correct one, simply run:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

which will output a list of current `.desktop` files, used in the launcher.

Comment: Or just use [`nemo`](http://askubuntu.com/a/602877/344926)...  **>:-)**

Comment: Comment by [derwiwie](http://askubuntu.com/users/97594/derwiwie) Note that in order for the above gsettings command to print nautilus at all, nautilus needs to be locked/pinned to the launcher.

Comment: @Fabby "Be Nice :)" about gksu and nautilus: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17687/do-we-engage-in-too-much-gksu-bashing/17691#17691

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix upvoted your answer there...  Never in chat any more?

Comment: @Fabby No. I'm kind of an anti-war guy and the HRC extremists (or some people like that) leveled a 30 day chat ban against me last year. So I decided it was a bad place to hang out. Thanks for upvoting my anti-anti-gksu gedit answer though :)

Answer (score 4):

## Use `pkexec` instead of `gksu`

The use of `gksu` and `gksudo` is [not recommended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default/284717#284717) any more. The recommended method is to use **[Polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit)**. The easiest way to add Polkit files for `Nautilus` is to install **`nautilus-admin`**

To install `nautilus-admin` in Ubuntu, open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin
```

**The rest involves editing the `nautilus.desktop file and adding the correct command:**

1. Copy the `nautilus.desktop` file, representing nautilus in the launcher, from the global directory `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`

   cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
2. Open the file with (e.g.) `gedit`, look for the line:

   Actions=Window;

Change it into:

```
Actions=Window;Open as Administrator;
```

Add to the very end of the file:

```
[Desktop Action Open as Administrator]
Name=Open as Administrator
Exec=pkexec nautilus
```

Save and close the file.

The added bonus of installing `nautilus-admin` is that within `Nautilus` you will also get **Open as Administrator / Edit as Administrator** items for folders / text files in the right click context menu. See [How do I start Nautilus as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root/868882#868882) for more details.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

For me under **Ubuntu 16.10** the relevant .desktop file for nautilus was

```
/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

Even though `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites` returned `application://org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`

Also note, that in order for the above `gsettings` command to print `nautilus` at all, `nautilus` needs to be locked/pinned to the launcher.