# 16.04 - sudo nautilus does not open in unity bar

Tags: unity, nautilus, 16.04

In **Ubuntu 16.04**: when I run `sudo nautilus` from the terminal, a new window pops up but no arrow indicating an opened window appears besides the nautilus icon at the unity panel. When I minimize the root window and then click again on the icon, instead of opening the root window, a new non-root window pops up and suddenly two arrows appear near the nautilus icon. (Not even scrolling on top of the icon works to show the minimized window.) When I close the non-root window, only then the arrow indicating the root window stays on the panel and everything works like it should.

I also tried removing the nautilus icon from the panel and run `sudo nautilus` from the terminal. In that case a new icon appears with the arrow and everything behaves normal.

Is there a way to fix this? It is annoying.

Comment: Try `gksu` or `gksudo nautilus` because sudo wont really create a correct execution environment for GTK (programs w/ gui) programs.

Comment: No, not even with `gksu`. And in addition to that, after running `gksu nautilus` my wallpaper reset to the default 16.04-one. Only after clicking the nautilus icon again, the arrows appeared and my custom wallpaper is back.

Comment: Now that is very interesting.... I have literally no idea whats going on there. Have you tried `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Comment to the GUI: When I run e.g. `sudo kate` it does show the arrow besides an existing icon... And I have never used `gksu` on 14.04 and still after running `sudo nautilus` there the arrow showed every time...

Comment: I installed the newest automatic updates through the update manager few minutes before posting this question and now I did it again through terminal. The issue remains. Also I have just spotted that after closing the nautilus root window, the terminal does not seem to end the process untill I press Ctrl-C. (While running `sudo kate` and closing the window, the terminal resets itself normally.)

Comment: Hmmm.... I have no idea then :c

Comment: The bug remains even after upgrade to `4.4.0-64-generic`.

Answer (score 6):

First killall nautilus processes:

`sudo killall nautilus`

Then re-install the data package:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data`

Comment: Please, first read, then post. In the first answer I added a comment (May 24), that `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data` does not solve it. Now you are proposing it as an answer. And it is also a duplicate of an existing solution that has been already linked to the provious answer.

Comment: @VáclavPavlík, I'm proposing you killall nautilus processes before running the re-install.  It works for me, so it's an answer.

Comment: Please read **again and carefully** the third line in the answer from May 22, especially the first three words. Your post is no different from what has already been suggested.

Comment: @VáclavPavlík, The solution works for me; the answer you're referring to doesn't have an explicit command for the Ubuntu OS and therefore isn't very helpful for people who don't understand what `kill` is.  My answer is more descriptive and might help someone down the line whose problem might be solved, just as it was for me.

Comment: it works for me with kill all before reinstall

Comment: `sudo killall nautilus` was enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.6. I followed these instructions and it's working now. 
[Nautilus won't launch [16.04]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770134/nautilus-wont-launch-16-04)

Kill nautilus process, reinstall data:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data
```

and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data` does not solve it.

Answer (score 1):

For ownership of files [reasons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications), using `sudo` for `nautilus` is not preferable.
Having researched various responses, in particular [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/881700/210504) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default/284717#284717) post, neither are the `gksu` or `gksudo` commands.

Instead, it's suggested to use `pkexec`. You can install this and add it to `nautilus` via :

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin
```

Running `pkexec` from a **terminal** will still **not** let you see the window on the unity bar.

However, by installing `pkexec` through `nautilus-admin` there is a **right click option** in user version of `nautilus` to open as an administrator.
I found this window will retain an arrow in the unity bar along with the original window it was opened from (ie, close the original window just to have an administrator `nautilus` window open)!

Comment: I believe that there must be a better way to make nautilus communicate with the unity bar. I was looking into a response given on a similar [problem](https://superuser.com/a/1038923/742993) which started looking at adding root to a group called dbus. . However, using Ubuntu 16.04 I cannot find such a group listed in /etc/group as suggested.

Comment: This seemed relevant seeming errors when running `sudo nautilus` often seem to have references to Dbus. ie:
"_Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name..._"
Presumably Dbus allows communication to the unity bar of the app's status?

Comment: Rather than posting two comments under your own answer, I believe you can edit your answer by clicking the `edit` button.

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix! I intended to add as comments, to keep the solution clear. I wanted to generate discussion of a potential better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There might be possibility of another File Manager is running in background. 
I had the same problem previously, Nemo was running in background. After killing Nemo process Nautilus started to work. (As I never use Nemo, I removed that program and now everything works great).

*note: As I don't have enough reputation to add comment, I have given answer here. Thanks*

Answer (score -1):

Method:
Just open the terminal and type `nautilus`.

The disk icons will show up again and they will not disappear when you minimize them.

Had the same problem since I removed the disk icon (not nautilus icon) from the unity bar.

`apt-get remove` and `apt-get install` commands won't work.

Comment: Thanks but `nautilus` command works fine for me, `sudo nautilus` is what causes the problem.