# Nautilus won't launch [16.04]

Tags: nautilus, 16.04

If I try to launch Nautilus in whatever way (from Unity, Terminal), it doesn't launch. Terminal gives me these outputs:

**launch**

```
name@machine:~$ nautilus

(nautilus:4367): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.nautilus.preferences' is not installed

Trasovací/ladící past (SIGTRAP) (core dumped [obraz paměti uložen])
```

**launch with sudo**

```
name@machine:~$ sudo nautilus

(nautilus:4672): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(nautilus:4672): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.nautilus.preferences' is not installed

Trasovací/ladící past (SIGTRAP) (core dumped [obraz paměti uložen])
```

**check**

```
name@machine:~$ nautilus -c
running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory

(nautilus:4689): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.nautilus.preferences' is not installed

Trasovací/ladící past (SIGTRAP) (core dumped [obraz paměti uložen])
```

I tried to reinstall Nautilus (with purge), reboot, remove ~/.config/nautilus, step by step at first and then all at once but nothing worked. I haven't changed any configuration or made any significant changes in Ubuntu system since installation. Yesterday Nautilus worked, today doesn't. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: After seeing what you have tried already, this looks like something you can't fix yourself. I suggest you report this as a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/.

Comment: sudo killall nautilus; 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus nautilus-data gnome-system-monitor; 
journalctl -f; 
nautilus -c

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The schema `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences` is defined in the file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.nautilus.gschema.xml` which is in the package `nautilus-data`. Maybe it got damaged somehow.

Use

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data
```

to install that package again.

Comment: That file had been missing completely. Solution worked, thank you. I thought it could be caused by some broken or missing file. Are you specialist or do you found out that somehow? Is there a way how to recognize, which package has broken or missing file (at least the missing one, broken files are always difficult to spot)? Why nautilus-data cannot be removed if I purge nautilus and with all its no longer used dependencies (is it used by another gnome-based package)?

Comment: in my case it still doesn't work. I had to execute sudo nautilus ...

Comment: @bogdan.rusu Same here

Comment: The correct answer should be @Efi Kaltirimidou

Answer (score 156):

For me terminating the running nautilus process and restarting it worked.

```
ps awx | grep nautilus
```

I found the process id and then terminated it with

```
sudo kill -TERM <id>
```

Comment: That is what sometimes happens on my Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and your solution is exactly what I've needed.

Comment: Or you can kill it from process monitor.

Comment: wow.. this piece of code helped me. Thanks

Comment: Commands didn't help me (or maybe I used the wrong ID), but killing nautilus from the system monitor did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: For me a simple `pkill nautilus` did the same trick, on Ubuntu 16.04. Skips looking up any process ID.

Answer (score 19):

`killall nautilus`

will kill all instances.

Comment: By far the simplest solution. Should be the top answer.