# Alternatives to restart nautilus, besides killall and -q?

Tags: nautilus

Nautilus froze and I had to terminate it using

```
killall nautilus
```

however now everytime I open nautilus it does not work properly: It seems to respond to the mouse (as clicking on [x] closes the window) but the interface does not update, so any click on any folder does not show its contents. I can't even resize the nautilus window, it just acts as if it is completely frozen.

The only two options (besides restarting the computer) are

```
nautilus -q

killall nautilus
```

but neither helps, as this happens everytime I open nautilus.

What else can I try to get it to work?

Comment: You can restart GNOME by pressing `Alt+F2` then `r` {reference](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/07/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-from-command.html)

Comment: @24601 is it necessary to restart GNOME though? Everything is working fine besides nautilus

Comment: Nautilus is the default file manager for GNOME. See [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/nautilus.1.html)

Comment: @24601 worked perfectly, if you submit it as an answer I can accept it

Comment: Done. Thank you. I upvoted your question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restart GNOME by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd>.

Nautilus is the default file manager for GNOME.

[reference](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/nautilus.1.html)