# "Files" File manager is not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, files, filemanager

"Files" File manager is not working on my Ubuntu 20.04 system.

If I try to open it from terminal by using `nautilus` command, still nothing is happening.

But if I try with `sudo nautilus` command then It can open.
But each time I dont want to open it through terminal command.
I want it to open through UI only as it was working before.

I had recently installed docker on my system. I thought this was happening because of docker installation. so I completely uninstalled docker using [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021506/1503528), but still issue has not solved.

I have also tried below solutions. But nothing has worked for me.

1. [reinstalling nautilus-data using below command](https://askubuntu.com/a/770192/1503528)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data
```

2. [terminating the running nautilus process and restarting it using below commands](https://askubuntu.com/a/875311/1503528)

```
ps awx | grep nautilus
sudo kill -TERM <id>
```

3. [Uninstalling and reinstalling Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/876810/1503528)

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus

sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Comment: You've likely run it before via `sudo nautilus` & made a change that as a consequence, has removed access from your user for one of it's configuration files.  It shouldn't be run with `sudo`, or should you do it, you should be careful to not change ownership away from your own $USER and give ownership to root.   Look for files in $HOME that aren't owned by you anymore & correct  your ownership

Answer (score 3):

### Question

The issue was I had changed ownership of nautilus to root user only while doing something. Because of that I was not able to start nautilus from terminal OR "Files" from UI as a my regular USER.

Thanks to [@guiverc. His Comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371911/files-file-manager-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04#comment2359653_1371911) helped me to understand what exactly was happened.

### Solution:

1. I started nautilus through `sudo nautilus` command.
2. In home directory right click and selected Properties.
3. In permissions tab changed user to my USER. Now I can open "Files" as it was working before.