# Nautilus file manager not working on Ubuntu 20.04 Please Help

Tags: permissions, nautilus

I use Ubuntu 20.04, the problem is the Files app in the system does not open.
I tried different method such as reinstalling nautilus, its data. But non of it seems to work as in I still cannot open the app. I tried changing the permissions of the home directory as well but that didn't work out either. This all started when I installed OBS. But I uninstalled that as well.
links to the post I referred : ["Files" File manager is not working on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371911/files-file-manager-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)
I tried everything from this post but non of that worked for me so please can anyone help me

i tried this line to reinstall nautilus

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

then I tried to reinstall its data

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data
```

and the above lines gave a successful message yet only

```
sudo nautilus
```

worked but only showed me the root and efi.
As you can clearly see that only efi and root are visible  [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwIeZ.png)

So I went forward and did the change permission thing of the home directory so i did that to the home folder in the root drive.
And one more thing to note is whenever i try to launch the nautilus my swap memory suddenly rises and the system slows for about a minute. Despite the fact that i have 12Gb of physical memory but during that time only 1 Gb is used and around 26% to 45% of swap is used.

Comment: If you read the link that you provided, then you already have a good idea that we are going to ask about improper `sudo` use and the ownership/permissions of Nautilus. Since you "tried everything", you already have that information and other troubleshooting output readily available, so why is none of it in your Question?

Comment: well because the outputs discussed in that post are the same ones that i got  if you want i can post the outputs as well

Comment: Right now it seems like a duplicate with a simple answer, so please show us how you determined that it's not a duplicate. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1376099/edit); do not add new information in comments.