# Nautilus is not opening

Tags: nautilus

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

When I reboot/start the system it works perfectly fine, but then after some time the computer has been running if I try to open the file manager it doesn't open anymore.

Trying to opening it via UI just loads for a while and then nothing happens. Running it via command line makes it load a while again and then this message appears
(translated from Italian, the message may not be exactly this in English):

```
Failed to register: Timeout reached

(org.gnome.Nautilus:47297): Tracker-WARNING **: 08:26:44.192: Could not delete '.meta.isrunning': File or directory doesn't exist
```

Finally, if I run it with `sudo nautilus` it works. but of course this means that to open the file manager I have to write that and insert my password.

Now, googling a bit got me to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371911/files-file-manager-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04), and I tried all the things the OP tried and the commented solutions as well. The thing is: I had never run nautilus as root before, so it's not what the first commenter said. No file I could find is owned by someone else than me (the only user on the PC), so it's not that either.
Also, the weird thing is that as I said it works for a bit after I first open the PC (sleep mode doesn't count, only starting/restarting the system) but then out of seemingly nowhere it stops.

What can I do?

Comment: "sudo nautilus" will break your system. Your issue may be a consequence of such actions . Never run *any* graphical applications as root with "sudo". This looks like your case: https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng/-/issues/187

Answer (score 0):

Starting `nautilus` as `root` is at the root of your problems.

When `nautilus` starts, it creates (as `root` in your case) configuration files, cache directories, etc., suitably protected against access by other users.

Subsequently, when you run `nautilus` as `$USER`, you have access problems.

This is a Well Known Problem with running graphical programs (or any program that saves context) as `root`. Don't do it.

To find the files not owned by `$USER`:

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -ls
```

To blindly 'fix' all the ownerships,

```
sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -r sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g)
```

Read `man find xargs chown id`.