# Keyboard shortcut in Nemo to open terminal in active folder

Tags: nemo

Nautilus has the ability to assign a keyboard shortcut to [open a terminal at the current folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here).

Is this possible in Nemo (I have version 2.6.7, running on Linux Mint 17.2)?

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Mint is off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to migrate this question there?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of...  Questions can only be migrated to the meta site here.

Comment: Migrated manually [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253211/keyboard-shortcut-in-nemo-to-open-terminal-in-active-folder)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>F4</kbd>

You need to install the `nemo-terminal` package for it to work. You can get it from the [Webupd8 Nemo PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo). Add it to your sources and install the terminal extension:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get install nemo-terminal
```

Comment: Good news: `nemo-terminal` is already available by default in my distro (Mint 17.2). Bad news: it doesn't do anything when I press `F4`. Could a logout be needed perhaps?

Comment: This answer was filed before the OP declared he is on a distribution other than Ubuntu. This procedure is successful on Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried it and success.  After running above two commands, you can Right click in the Nemo window, and you will see the "Open Terminal"

Comment: Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.3: nemo-terminal package is not installed.  When I tried the above add-apt-repository I got a very strong message: "Only use this PPA in Ubuntu. Don't use it in Linux Mint!
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo"

Comment: However, installing just going sudo apt-get install nemo-terminal then means that you can at least emulate right-click (shift-F10) when focus is on a directory, and this context menu then contains an item "Open in Terminal" which it didn't before.

Comment: Does this still work in Ubuntu 20.04 and is this still the right way to install. I get the following warning suggesting it is not: " !!! For Nemo 3.x you'll need to use a different PPA: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/11/nemo-320-with-unity-patches-and-without.html
"

Comment: I found the following more reliable and you can customize the key that should be used: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253211/keyboard-shortcut-in-nemo-to-open-terminal-in-active-folder (Ubuntu 20.04)