# "Open in terminal" Keyboard Shortcut not working in 17.10

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, 17.10, configure

[Keyboard shortcut for "open a terminal here"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here)

I followed the steps mentioned in in the top voted answer in the above link for my Ubuntu **16.04** and my custom keyboard shortcut for "open in terminal", when a directory in nautilus was opened, worked perfectly.

However I recently **upgraded to 17.10**, and though the `~/.config/nautilus/accels` file remained unchanged, nothing happens when I press the keyboard keys for it now when Nautilus is opened.

I also turned `can-change-accels` "on" from the `dconf-editor` which somehow had turned false after upgrading to 17.10

Please help me fix this problem

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the Compiz, Install the `compizconfig-settings-manager`

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open CompizConfig Setting Manager  and disable the Command plugin as below

[image]

Unselect the Commands plugin and it should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Installed it, but the command option was  already unselected

Comment: I upgraded to 17.10 and had the same problem and this worked for me

Comment: Didn't work for me though