# Nautilus shortcut for "Open in Terminal" and gvfs

Tags: scripts, shortcut-keys, nautilus, shortcuts, perl

I am trying to assign a shortcut to "Open in Terminal" in Nautilus. I have implemented the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/445951/1098236) with nautilus-scripts and the Perl file.

While this solution works well for local files and desktop, it fails for gvfs mounted shares, like Samba, FTP, FTPS, SFTP, WebDav, etc. To add to the misery, under the sftp protocol, the mounted directory in /run/user/1001/gvfs seems to be different if a user or port is entered or not in the link.

As the right-click menu "Open the Terminal" handles these cases well, I also took a look at the source code of the nautilus-open-terminal plugin [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eemilien-klein/nautilus-open-terminal/head/view/head:/src/nautilus-open-terminal.c), but it seems too complicated for the little Perl knowledge that I have.

Is there an easy solution to this? Or maybe some Perl expert is able to modify the script to handle the gvfs?