# Adding a Keyboard Shortcut to Gnome Files Context Menu Items in 20.04

Tags: nautilus

Is there a way to add a keyboard shortcuts to items in the context menu (the menu that pops up when you right click) in Gnome Files? Specifically, I want to give "Open in Terminal" a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcut for "open a terminal here"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option to customize shortcuts in Gnome Files nor any other Gnome application. However, for your specific question on how to implement a shortcut for "Opening Terminal Here", there is a good workaround [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here?noredirect=1&lq=1) (answer by amartin1911) that still works in Ubuntu 20.04 (using it myself since a few years).

It involves creating a nautilus-script for opening the terminal. Nautilus scripts can be bound to a shortcut key.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't add an additional item to the context menu. But this will work fine. Thanks