# Execute Nautilus script with key combination

Tags: shortcut-keys, nautilus

I used the method described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079882/1549300) to run custom scripts using a keyboard shortcut in Nautilus, which consists of dropping the script in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` and editing the file `~/.config/nautilus/scripts-accels` to include the line `<shortcut> <script_filename>`.

It works, but only with standalone keys, even though the combination appears under scripts in the context menu when I use `<Alt>+T` as the shortcut. I tried changing the line to `<Alt>T`, `<Alt>+t` and many different variations with different modifiers and none worked.

I use Nautilus 3.36.3.
[Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) was little help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct notation is `<Alt>t`. Unfortunately, it is a hit and miss indeed. Apparently, not all Alt-cobinations are recognized. For me (on Ubuntu 21.10), `<Alt>t` also does not work. `<Alt>q`, `<Alt>a` doesn't, `<Control><Alt>a` however does. So for practical purposes, you will have to test and stick on a combination that works.

Comment: Thank you. Well that's unfortunate, I'll be sticking with F3 for now.
I wonder if this is intended or a bug as I couldn't find mentions of either. If it's the latter I might file a bug report.