# Shortcut to open the terminal specific directory

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, shortcuts

I'd like to know the shortcut that lets you open a terminal window in a specific directory just like when you press the left button on it and you click on 'Open in terminal' in the pop-up menu.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Are you referring to the Nautilus file manager? That [hasn't worked for several releases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68078/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-a-terminal-here) now. In Nemo, it's F4.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest way in a default installation is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>. There is no single shortcut key to directly open a terminal.

*Caveat* In Ubuntu 22.04 (Files 42.2) this is broken. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> now opens the folder menu of the bar (⁞) instead of the right-click context menu. That behavior also breaks the use of the Python extension described below to a large extent. Still, assigning a nautilus specific shortcut using the extension works.

A good way to implement a direct shortcut key is to replace the default extension by a nautilus python extension, [nautilus-open-any-terminal](https://github.com/Stunkymonkey/nautilus-open-any-terminal). Next to allowing for a single shortcut key, it allows you to substitute a terminal of your choice, if you wish.

1. Quit nautilus fully

   nautilus -q
2. Make sure `python3-nautilus` is installed: `sudo apt install python3-nautilus`
3. Install the extension, either using `pip` as [indicated on the website](https://github.com/Stunkymonkey/nautilus-open-any-terminal/blob/master/nautilus_open_any_terminal/open_any_terminal_extension.py), or by [grabbing the source code](https://github.com/Stunkymonkey/nautilus-open-any-terminal/blob/master/nautilus_open_any_terminal/open_any_terminal_extension.py) and placing it in a text file `~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/open_any_terminal_extension.py`.
4. Enable the dconf settings

   `glib-compile-schemas ~/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`
5. Define the settings:

`gsettings set com.github.stunkymonkey.nautilus-open-any-terminal terminal gnome-terminal`

Supply `gnome-terminal`  or any other of the terminals listed in the source code.

`gsettings set com.github.stunkymonkey.nautilus-open-any-terminal keybindings '<Ctrl><Alt>t'`

to set the Nautilus keybinding for opening the terminal.

`gsettings set com.github.stunkymonkey.nautilus-open-any-terminal new-tab true`

if you want to open the current directory in a new tab in a running instance. Otherwise, it will be a new window.

**Bonus tips:**

- Remove the now superfluous default extension: `sudo apt remove nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal`.
- Enable hotkeys in the right-click menu by editing the source code of the extension: where the menu label is defined, add an underscore before the letter you want to activate as a hotkey for the function, as in

  label=_(u"Op_en {} Here").format(terminal.title()),

With this example, also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> will work to open a terminal here.

Comment: `Ctrl+F10 E` brings up the Properties window on my system.

Comment: @Jos This has become Ctrl+F10+r on Ubuntu 20.10 (Files 40). Anyway, you can select another menu hotkey of course.

Comment: `CTRL + F10 + e` in *Files/Nautilus* works for me on Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have recently moved to `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS` and had the exact issue of not being able to open the terminal on the current directory. For example, in windows I could use `alt+d` and then write `cmd`, and the terminal would open in the current directory.

This is the closest I could get to open terminal in the current working directory using just the keyboard (it has a bit more keystroke but might be useful also)

When we are in a folder and want to open the terminal at the same place, then the following keystroke brings the terminal up in the current directory

`shift+f10` then `two up arrow` keystroke and `enter`

I have to say I came across this by accident while pressing some keys on my keyboard.

I hope it helps :)

UPDATE I: I just noticed one limitation of this approach while using the above-mentioned approach. If I am already selecting one file/folder, then `shift+f10` does not open the floating window that has `Open in Terminal` option, but it opens another floating window that is specifically related to the file/folder I have selected.

UPDATE II: Found a more convinent way `shift+f10` + `e`. This works like a charm (given the limitation mentioned in UPDATE I sadly)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).