# Does nautilus block hotkeys?

Tags: nautilus

I just installed Ubuntu LTS 22.04. I have guake installed and use the F12 hotkey for opening the Guake window. This usually works fine, except for if the active window is Files (presumably Nautilus, by default now). However, nothing happens apparently in Nautilus -- I can't be sure it's a hotkey set for anything here.

Does Nautilus block the F12 hotkey? If so, how can I turn that off?

Comment: F12 is or was(?) "open terminal here"  You can overwrite/reuse F12 using this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1079882/15811

Comment: You are using Wayland. Wayland (still) does not support global shortcuts. Instead, set this shortcut key up as decribed here: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/12/how-to-use-guake-terminal-under-wayland.html, then it should work everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nautilus does *not* block global shortcut keys. No application can: global shortcut keys always have priority over application specific shortcuts.

The issue you see is because Ubuntu 22.04 runs on Wayland by default. Wayland does not (yet) support application specific global keyboard shortcuts. Only global shortcuts defined through the desktop environment are supported. Application defined shortcut keys do not work if an application that natively runs on Wayland application has keyboard focus.

See [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/12/how-to-use-guake-terminal-under-wayland.html) to work around in the case of Guake terminal.